# Errors with Flask Security: ImportError: cannot import name 'hash_password' from 'flask_security'

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm following a Youtube video, trying to setup Flask log in form that communicates with database. However, I'm getting errors by following a Flask guide, can anyone check the same code on their machine?

Starting here: https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html
Click on section: Basic SQLAlchemy Application with session

I'm running on Windows.

I presume you input these in your Terminal (in brackets run status, not sure if this is an issue)

```
$ python3 -m venv pymyenv (error)
$ . pymyenv/bin/activate (error)
$ pip install flask-security-too[common] sqlalchemy (success)
```

I've copied code to individual .py files:

```
app.py
database.py
models.py
```

As per above.

Error I receive is as follows:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'hash_password' from 'flask_security'
```

Comment: What are the errors that you get when creating and activating the virtualenv?

Comment: PS C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Desktop\FlaskSecureTRY> python3 -m venv pymyenv
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
PS C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Desktop\FlaskSecureTRY>

Comment: PS C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Desktop\FlaskSecureTRY> . pymyenv/bin/activate
. : The term 'pymyenv/bin/activate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ . pymyenv/bin/activate
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pymyenv/bin/activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: These are two errors that I get. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
from flask_security import hash_password
```

with

```
from flask_security.utils import hash_password
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I get: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_security.utils'`. `flask-security-too` is installed, I double checked.